# save and load unserialized pytorch pretrained model

Tags: c++, pytorch

for normal saving and loading pytorch model is quite simple.

in python I can use `torch.save(model, FilePath)` and in c++`torch::jit::load(FilePath)`. and the saved model and c++ load code can be placed in one directory. However, there is a limitation that binary file cannot be contained in the directory in the production mode (Please don't ask me why the binary file cannot be contained, I also wondering).

So, I want to know how to save the pytorch model from python without serializtion and load this model in c++. Is it possible?

Answer (score 0):

Use the ONNX file format. Pytorch can output files in this format, and then you should be able to find a related library to load this in C++.